# SQL Previous Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, date, view, filter

I have a view that shows be data for Fiscal Year to Date. I need another view that will show previous fiscal year. I have a table that contains fiscal year start and end dates. ie 7/1/YYYY to 6/30/YYYY.

Comment: And you have tried...?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Please provide view & column names, along with sample data and desired output.

Comment: I am trying to create a view based on Order# and Previous Fiscal Year. The column would be order date. I want the view to show only the previous fiscal year of data, but I need dynamic since it will be used for reporting purposes and I dont want to have to manually filter on the fiscal year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a User-Defined Function based on the Fiscal year of your application.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnc_FiscalYear(
    @AsOf           DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Answer     INT

    -- You define what you want here (July being your changeover month)
    IF ( MONTH(@AsOf) < 7 )
        SET @Answer = YEAR(@AsOf) - 1
    ELSE
        SET @Answer = YEAR(@AsOf)


    RETURN @Answer

END

GO
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.fnc_FiscalYear('7/1/2016')


SELECT dbo.fnc_FiscalYear('6/30/2015')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution will work.

Between DATEADD(Month,6,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,1,GETDATE())-2,0)) and
      DATEADD(month,6,DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-1,0)))

Comment: This solution actually will not work because it would be previous Fiscal year to date and not previous fiscal year